# Where is the proper place to save the authentication token in SSO scenarios?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, caddy

[Caddy](https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy) web server has a [forward_auth](https://caddyserver.com/docs/caddyfile/directives/forward_auth) directive, that as the name suggests, can forward any incoming request to an outside source and that outside source can decide on whether to accept the request and reply so that `Caddy` continues the handling of the request or to deny it and let say redirect the user to a login page.

I have implemented such a **authentication gateway** and for now, it uses the **Remote IP** and **X-Forwarded-For** header (`Caddy` puts remote IP in that header), for identification of the users. I know that it means, once an IP is logged in, user will have access to resources from everywhere (any browser and session) as long as the IP is authorized (that is, the same IP).

My question is about other similar solutions such as **Cloudflare Zero Trust** that can authorize requests over a logged in browser profile. (as long as the profile of the browser is the one that user logged in with, they will grant access even on separate browser tabs)

I wonder how the likes of **Cloudflare Zero Trust** do that. I mean saving cookies needs access to the Local storage, but using that means that, the **authentication gateway** must be a full-fledged website that loads on the browser of the client for any request (and that's slow and expensive). on the other hand, Session Storage only applies to the current browser session (tab) and not the tab next to it.

Any clarifications on how and where the authentication tokens should be stored, is really appreciated.